# How do the Render Engine and JavaScript Engine Communicate in a browser?

Tags: javascript, web, browser, v8, blink

I'm looking for a detailed answer on this.

**What I already Know**

So I have some understanding about the call stack and callbacks, and that the browser add functionality through web APIs which add callbacks through the event loop. I also read somewhere about the JS engine having an API.

**What I want to understand**

- How are the web APIs exposed to the JS engine? (If this is about the
  JS engine having an API, some description on how that API works would
  do)
- How can the behavior of the Render Engine be manipulated through
  JavaScript, like manipulating the DOM, CSSOM etc.? (If I understood
  correctly, this is the equivalent of asking how web APIs work)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a (C++ etc.) application development perspective, JavaScript engines are embeddable libraries; and a browser is one such embedder. Any library defines a public interface through which it can be used -- its Application Programming Interface (or API for short). There is no standard for what a JS engine's API should look like; each engine defines its own, and evolves it as necessary over time. V8's is [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/include/v8.h).

The core functionality of a JS engine's API is to allow the embedder to provide objects and functions to the JavaScript environment that are backed by the embedder's own C++ implementations. Essentially, this defines a mapping, sometimes also called "bindings". For example, the embedder can say "I want there to be a `document` object, and it should appear to have a property `.location` that's backed by my getter function `DocumentLocationGetter() {...}`, and it should (appear to) have a method `.createElement()` that's backed by my other function `DocumentCreateElement(...) {...}`", and so on.

And that's the answer to both of your questions: the browser exposes certain functions to JavaScript that can then be called from there. The browser decides what to do when such a function is called (e.g.: add or remove a DOM node, change a CSS property, store an event handler in some element's event handlers list, ...). Of course the browser/embedder can also call into the JS engine, for example when invoking an event handler, it can tell the engine "please execute function `button1_clicked` now".

For more details, see e.g. [v8.dev/docs/embed](https://v8.dev/docs/embed).